# How can I make React-admin ReferenceField display clickable value linked to another table

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am new in ReactJs. I was trying to use 'react-admin' library to make a simple admin ui. I have flask-api with two tables. Product and images tables. They have one-to-many relationship. So one has foreign key from another one. Everything works fine except one. I can't display ReferenceField of images table in product table. When I updated react code I can see clickable value of one of columns of images table in product table. However, values disappear after 2-3 seconds. Instead warning icon svg emerges.

This is what I can see in console: ***index.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***

And here are the codes.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from "react-admin";
import dataProvider from "./dataProvider";
import { ProductList, ProductCreate, ProductEdit } from "./products";
import { ImageList, ImageCreate, ImageEdit } from "./images";

import { UserIcon, PostIcon, ImageIcon } from "@material-ui/icons/Group";

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider(" http://localhost:5000")}>
    <Resource
      name="products"
      list={ProductList}
      create={ProductCreate}
      edit={ProductEdit}
      icon={UserIcon}
    />

    <Resource
    
      name="images"
      list={ImageList}
      edit={ImageEdit}
      create={ImageCreate}
      icon={PostIcon}
    />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

products.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  ReferenceField,
  ReferenceInput,
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput,
  Create,
  EditButton,
  SelectInput,
  NumberField
} from "react-admin";

export const ProductList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="type" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <NumberField source="price" />
      <ReferenceField source="image_id" reference="images" allowEmpty>
          <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>

      <NumberField source="in_stock" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);


export const ProductCreate = (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="type" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="price" />
      <ReferenceInput source="image_id" reference="images" allowEmpty>
          <SelectInput optionText="name" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="in_stock" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);

export const ProductEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput disabled source="id" />
      <TextInput source="type" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="price" />
      <ReferenceInput source="image_id" reference="images" allowEmpty>
          <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="in_stock" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

images.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput,
  Create,
  EditButton,
} from "react-admin";

export const ImageList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="type" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <TextField source="body" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);

export const ImageCreate = (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      {/* <TextInput source="id" /> */}
      <TextInput source="type" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="body" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);

export const ImageEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput disabled source="id" />
      <TextInput source="type" />
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="body" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

dataProvider.js

```
import { stringify } from "query-string";
import { fetchUtils } from "ra-core";

var __assign =
  (this && this.__assign) ||
  function () {
    __assign =
      Object.assign ||
      function (t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
          s = arguments[i];
          for (var p in s)
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p)) t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
      };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
  };


export default (function (apiUrl, httpClient) {
  if (httpClient === void 0) {
    httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;
  }
  return {

    getList: (resource, params) => {
      const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
      const { field, order } = params.sort;
      const query = {
        sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
        range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
        filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
      };
      const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

      return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
        data: json,
        total: 10,
        //   total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range'), 10),
          // total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
      }));
    },


    getOne: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id).then(
        function (_a) {
          var json = _a.json;
          return {
            data: json,
          };
        }
      );
    },
    getMany: function (resource, params) {
      var query = {
        q: JSON.stringify({
          filters: [{ name: "id", val: params.ids, op: "in" }],
        }),
      };
      var url = apiUrl + "/" + resource + "?" + stringify(query);
      return httpClient(url).then(function (_a) {
        return { data: _a.json.objects };
      });
    },
    getManyReference: function (resource, params) {
      var _a;
      var _b = params.pagination,
        page = _b.page,
        perPage = _b.perPage;
      var _c = params.sort,
        field = _c.field,
        order = _c.order;
      var query = {
        sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
        range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
        filter: JSON.stringify(
          __assign(
            __assign({}, params.filter),
            ((_a = {}), (_a[params.target] = params.id), _a)
          )
        ),
      };
      var url = apiUrl + "/" + resource + "?" + stringify(query);
      return httpClient(url).then(function (_a) {
        var headers = _a.headers,
          json = _a.json;
        if (!headers.has("content-range")) {
          throw new Error(
            "The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?"
          );
        }
        return {
          data: json,
          total: parseInt(headers.get("content-range").split("/").pop(), 10),
        };
      });
    },
    update: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return { data: json };
      });
    },
    // simple-rest doesn't handle provide an updateMany route, so we fallback to calling update n times instead
    updateMany: function (resource, params) {
      return Promise.all(
        params.ids.map(function (id) {
          return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + id, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
          });
        })
      ).then(function (responses) {
        return {
          data: responses.map(function (_a) {
            var json = _a.json;
            return json.id;
          }),
        };
      });
    },

    create: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return {
          data: __assign(__assign({}, params.data), { id: json.id }),
        };
      });
    },


    delete: function (resource, params) {
      return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + params.id, {
        method: "DELETE",
      }).then(function (_a) {
        var json = _a.json;
        return { data: json };
      });
    },

    create: (resource, params) =>
      httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
      }).then(({ json }) => ({
        data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
      })),
    // simple-rest doesn't handle filters on DELETE route, so we fallback to calling DELETE n times instead
    deleteMany: function (resource, params) {
      return Promise.all(
        params.ids.map(function (id) {
          return httpClient(apiUrl + "/" + resource + "/" + id, {
            method: "DELETE",
          });
        })
      ).then(function (responses) {
        return {
          data: responses.map(function (_a) {
            var json = _a.json;
            return json.id;
          }),
        };
      });
    },
  };
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeSKT.png)

I am not able to find the reason. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like one or more of your .map() is running on 'undefined' or 'not array'. Would recommend to debug and see the values of 'responses', 'params.ids'.

Comment: I followed you suggestion and put console.log(params.id) in each api functions. All of them returned undefined value.